# Using a lens over something that isn't a functor

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have a lens(')

```
myLens' :: (Functor f) => (a -> f a) -> (s -> f s)
```

And I need a function

```
lensWithoutFunctor' :: ((a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)) -> (a -> f a) -> (s -> f s)
```

(The particular type I'm interested in is

```
type PopType x a = x -> Maybe (a, x)
```

which could be made into a Functor if I wanted)

Is there a better way to do this other than create a Functor-implementing newtype and then doing something involving "ala"?

Comment: I find these type signatures a bit too pseudo-codeish to understand what you're asking about. Please avoid using lowercase letters for placeholders that aren't type variables.

Comment: Is there any such type which couldn't be made into a Functor if you wanted? This looks sort of like a yoneda embedding to me.